# In Classic ASP reading cXML Files, is it required to point your dtd link to local files?

Tags: asp-classic, runtime-error, dtd, cxml-commercexml

Unfortunately, we've inherited an old Classic ASP site and are writing new code for a round trip punch-out site. Reading in the cXML file, we're continually erroring out on the 2nd line `!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.../cXML.dtd`.

If we capture the location of the `dtd` file and change it to a local file, i.e., `file:///c:/....dtd` it works. Is there no way to get this to work using the `http` location? I'd rather not store all the `dtd` file versions locally.

Our Code is:

```vb
    Dim olddtdvalue
    Dim newdtdvalue
    Dim xmlfilename
    olddtdvalue = "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/"
    newdtdvalue = "file:///d:/Websites/FSIResponsive/cXML/"
    xmlfilename ="PORS_" & formatdatetime(now,vblongdate) & " " & replace(formatdatetime(now,vblongtime),":","_") &  ".xml"
    set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    set f=fs.CreateTextFile("d:\WebSites\FSIResponsive\cXML\InFiles\" & xmlfilename,true)
    f.write("remote host: " & request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_HOST") & vbcrlf & vbcrlf)
    totalBytes = Request.TotalBytes
    If totalBytes > 0 Then
        xml = Request.BinaryRead( totalBytes )
        for i = 1 to totalBytes
            xmlstr = xmlstr + String(1,AscB(MidB(xml, i, 1)))
        Next
        f.write(xmlstr)
        xml2 = xmlstr
        xml2 = Replace(xml2,olddtdvalue,newdtdvalue)
    End if
    Set xdoc = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
'   Set xdoc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    xdoc.ValidateOnParse = True
    xdoc.async = False
    xdoc.resolveExternals = True
'   response.write xml2 
    loadStatus = xdoc.loadXML(xml2)
```

As you can see, we've tried using `MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0`, but that doesn't work either.

Thanks,
Alan

Update:
Here's the code I finally got working:

```
Dim xmlfilename
Dim URL
totalBytes = Request.TotalBytes
If totalBytes > 0 Then
    xml = Request.BinaryRead( totalBytes )
    for i = 1 to totalBytes
        xmlstr = xmlstr + String(1,AscB(MidB(xml, i, 1)))
    Next
    xml2 = xmlstr
End if
Set xdoc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xdoc.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
xdoc.setProperty "ProhibitDTD",False
xdoc.resolveExternals = True
xdoc.ValidateOnParse = True
xdoc.async =  False
loadStatus = xdoc.LoadXML(xml2)
```

Alan

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902554/xml-and-asp-retrieve-and-parse-a-remote-file